# Romantic 70s movie about a painter who gets plastic surgery in exchange for never seeing her rich boyfriend again

Tags: identify-this-movie

I saw a romantic 70s movie when I was a kid.

It is about a rich guy whose girlfriend is a painter. His mother disapproves. After a car accident disfigures her, she gets plastic surgery in exchange for never seeing him again. He is told she died. He discovers the truth by meeting her by chance, and recognizing her art. I remember there was some famous song.

What is the title of this movie?

Answer (score 8):

This is the exact plot of [The Promise](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0079756/combined) from 1979, which was also a Danielle Steele novel. I'd quote a [recap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Promise_%281979_film%29), but it's pretty much repeating what you've described, so I'll just add that the song in question is Melissa Manchester's ["I'll Never Say Goodbye"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DCDVRqn8cvw), which was nominated for an Oscar. [The trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fR1DOyMd20k), as well as the [movie itself](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LJJs9WXNdO8), are available on Youtube.

Comment: Open-and-shut. I think I have seen part of this once. I may have to revisit.